# Document references must have an even number of segments, but 8VMCfTZIAmOwRRb2JZsVT8K04o22 has 1

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying to add data to Firestore Database, when a user is created, this is where i am getting this error: `firestoreDb.document(uidd).collection("users").add(users)`

This is my code:

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            btnRegister.isEnabled = false
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                
                val success = true
                Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success")
                val user = auth.currentUser
                uidd = auth.currentUser!!.uid
                val users = User(
                    auth.currentUser?.uid.toString(),
                    age)

                Toast.makeText(this, uidd, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                firestoreDb = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                firestoreDb.document(uidd).collection("users").add(users)

             } else {
                val success = false
                Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.exception)
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
```

Please help me solve this issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly under the root of Firestore you find **collections**, not documents.

I think what you're trying to do is create a document for the user `uidd` in the `users` collection under the root. That'd be:

```
firestoreDb = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
firestoreDb.collection("users").document(uidd).set(users)
```

Also see the documentation on [setting a value to a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document).

Comment: Such a minor error and it took me 5-6 hrs to fix it!! THANK YOU for the solution, and yes I had seen those docs, but somehow still managed to make a mess.